# Avoid flickering on mouseover

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I'm trying to implement a little mouseover effect with jquery, but i'm stuck solving a flickering issue. I already tried inserting an delay for the mouseout but still i'm having troubles with the images.

Does anybody has a clue on this?

Kind regards, Sascha

Testing URL: [www.de-facto-magazin.de](http://www.de-facto-magazin.de)

```
$(".item").hover(

function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".title").show();
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".bg").show();
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".bg").addClass("transparent");
    $(this).find(".bg").removeClass("transparent");
    $(this).find(".title").addClass("colored");
}, function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".title").hide();
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".bg").hide();
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".title").removeClass("colored");

})​
```

Comment: It's flickering because the mouseout fires if you're in the gap between the images.

Comment: Instead, place the hover handler on #splash instead. That should work.

Comment: I'use some timeout for such events and try to use fadeIn and fadeOut events

Answer (score 1):

The best way to avoid a flicker is to have a separate hover event on the enclosing div (id="splash") to handle show/hide, and use the current event only to handle which div is active. Something along these lines (warning, code untested):

```
$("#splash").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find(".title").show();
        $(this).find(".bg").show();
    },function(){
        $(this).find(".title").hide();
        $(this).find(".bg").hide();
    }
);

$(".item").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".bg").addClass("transparent");
        $(this).find(".bg").removeClass("transparent");
        $(this).find(".title").addClass("colored");
    }
);
```

Comment: Thx for the quick support, the hint with the seperate hover on the "splash"-div did it.

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to mark the correct answer for the benefit of future googlers. Welcome to Stack Overflow!